# Uso do objeto XMLHttpRequest para realizar uma requisição HTTP assíncrona para atualizar dados no servidor sem atualização completa da página web

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

Possuo conhecimentos básicos e estou utilizando na aplicação: html/css, javascript, Nodejs, e para o banco - Mongodb - Mongoose.

Minha aplicação é bem simples, como podem ver na imagem abaixo, serve para publicação de textos contendo título e conteúdo. Preciso que assim que um novo conteúdo seja postado ele apareça logo abaixo, na lista de post, porém sem a atualização completa da página. Aceito referências ou videos explicando como fazer.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue abaixo o código javascript que tenho até agora.

```
// Publicar conteúdos
  app.get('/home', function(req, res, next){
    Postagem.find().sort({date:'desc'}).then(function (posts) {
      res.render('home', {posts: posts})//FORMULARIO HTML
    })
  })

// Recebendo os posts

  app.post('/home/postagens', function(req, res, next){
  var errosPostagem = []
  // Validação da postagem

  if(!req.body.titulo || typeof req.body.titulo == undefined || req.body.titulo == null ){
      errosPostagem.push({texto: "Título inválido "})
  }
  if(!req.body.conteudo || typeof req.body.conteudo == undefined || req.body.conteudo == null ){
      errosPostagem.push({texto: "Conteudo invalido "})
  }
      if(errosPostagem.length > 0){
        res.send('Título ou conteúdo inválido')
      }else {
            const novaPostagem = {
            titulo: req.body.titulo,
            conteudo: req.body.conteudo,
            date: req.body.date
            }
            new Postagem(novaPostagem).save().then(function(){
            }).catch(function (erro){
              res.send("Houve um erro: "+error)
            })
      }
  })
```

Comment: Você pode usar javascript pra mostrar os dados diretamente pro usuário, sem carregar de novo a página. Uma vez que o post é feito você criar uma lista com javascript e concatena os dados do formulário. Como por exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/224117/21077

Comment: Você deve mostrar sua aplicação melhor o problema pode está na forma que você está consumindo a API.

Comment: Ao invés de usar a antiga API `XMLHttpRequest`, você pode usar meios mais modernos, como o `fetch`. Para saber mais, leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/369072/69296).